# many maven modules, spring, single war

Tags: spring, maven, web-applications, module

It's been a while since I used maven last time for multi module projects. I'm building a webapp, and I'd like to have maven modules:

main module (that aggregates):

a) service - where I keep my logic, usual service layer

b) view - for web interface, talks to service layer only

c) api - for REST Api - talks to the same service layer

I know how to create web.xml  and servlet for view module - packaging is set to "war" - and that's something that I deploy on tomcat

But what with api module? Creating new web and servlet files + packaging it as war will create separate application on tomcat (which I don't want to have).

How to approach this issue? What if I'd like to add another module exposed to the end user? What's the best practice.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if i understand what you mean exactly. Is it as follows? you have your logic in a jar packaged service (a), and you have a web application(b) that uses the jar(a), and you want to have a REST service that uses the jar(a). Is that correct?

Comment: @stefaandutry - yes, you're right. In both "view" and "api" modules I want to have "@Controller" classes with "@RequestMappings", and I want "@Service" and "@Repository" annotated classes in "service" layer. Is that more clear?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want them to be 2 seperate applications on your tomcat? If you want them to be a single application on your tomcat, you will have to put the code in the same project. If you want them to be in a seperate application, keep in mind that having them with the same parent project will force you to make a new build of all your modules, even if only 1 should change.

Comment: Well... I just thought that keeping them in the same application is "the way" it should be done. That's why I was asking about convention. I guess there are prosand cons of kkeeping them in 2 separate applications. It's way more time consuming, and it's hard to share user session between them (am I right?) but on the other hand it's possible to redeploy only one of them, which is good from  modularisation perspective...

Comment: If you want the same session, then it is indeed a lot harder if it's different applications, but, according to what i find it should still be possible. take a look at http://lukaszbudnik.blogspot.be/2009/06/session-sharing-in-apache-tomcat.html . I hope this link will be of use.

Comment: @stefaandutry - thank you for the link. So it's possible to share session within multiple apps. My original question remains is it possible to keep all of that in single "war" application? Multiple apps can be a problem when I'd like to use some cloud service for hosting it.

Comment: The problem i see with that, is, if you're using apache-cxf for the REST-api, then you need to have some configuration for it in the web.xml (unless there's another way that i'm not aware of).

Comment: I think I'll stick to Spring MVC with my rest api.